# /dev/sdb1 : clean, 640729/122388848 and Keyboard is not working

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

`/dev/sdb1 : clean, 640729/122388848` files blocked, and keyboard is not active, keyboard doesn't work.

Ubuntu 16.04
NVIDIA GPU 1080ti

I cannot open the computer. `/dev/sdb1 : clean` *message* stays there.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is not working because keyboard is not working.

So how can I fix ?

I tried to fix via grub with root prompt:

$ sudo apt update
then receiving error : 
Could not resolve 'developer.download.nvidia.com'
Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'

$ sudo apt upgrade
Could not resolve 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'

(I use dual boot : Windows and Ubuntu.)

It was running, but it started not to run after 04.10.2018 gpu Windows driver updates. I cannot open ubuntu boot. Black screen frozen with "/dev/sdb1 : clean".

Is it temporary issue because of gpu driver updates or should I fix something ?

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard is functional? Does the same problem occur if you boot from a LiveUSB?

Comment: It is a dual boot.
I installed windows 10.
I installed ubuntu to ssd.
Before start, there are options :
Ubuntu
Windows etc.
Then keyboard is working in this screen.
But when I choose ubuntu, and enter,
Then : /dev/sdb1 message stays on screen and keyboard is not working. And not start.

Comment: It was working first. But after driver updates, it is not running anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I removed nvidia driver.
And installed again.
It is running now. Solved.

But I need to disables automatic NVIDIA driver updates/cuda updates/ubuntu updates updates,etc.

How can I do it ?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows as dual boot. Same NVIDIA GPU.
So I think I need to disable all to make stable system.